# tensorflow keras can't keep dropout during prediction phase (set learning phase not working)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In my neural network I'm trying to keep dropout active during prediction phase. I'm trying to accomplish this by using tensorflow.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(1) in tensorflow 2.0 RC.

The problem comes when I call model.compile which seems to turn off dropout during prediction phase.

The following following code shows how I set the learning phase. Before the model is compiled predictions are semi-random as expected. After the model is compiled predictions are no longer semi-random even though learning phase is still 1

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# load boston housing data
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import boston_housing
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = boston_housing.load_data()

# define model
K.clear_session()
K.set_learning_phase(1)
x = keras.Input(shape=(13,))
y = layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
y = layers.Dropout(0.5)(y)
y = layers.Dense(1)(y)

model = keras.Model(inputs=x,outputs=y)

# these results will have randomness
model.predict(x_test[0:1])
model.predict(x_test[0:1])
model.predict(x_test[0:1])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mse')


# now that model is compiled randomness is lost
model.predict(x_test[0:1])
model.predict(x_test[0:1])
model.predict(x_test[0:1])

print(K.learning_phase()) # == 1
```

This worked for me in past versions of tensorflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dropout` layer takes a `training` parameter that controls whether or not it is in training mode. Looking at the code on github, in the absence of the `training` parameter it *should* use the learning phase that has been set explicitly.

However, maybe this behaviour has changed somehow. [This github thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9412) suggests setting the training parameter explicitly, for example, as [one commenter](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9412#issuecomment-366487249) wrote:

```
import tensorflow.keras

inputs = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(3)(inputs)
outputs = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x, training=True)

model = tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```